# (PAUSE) and (LOOP) code for "Terminal" needed

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to create an Automator app to include a workflow that will play a sound in a loop preceded by a 1 min pause.
I want to do this without using elements from the "actions" library, but writing this part entirely in the "Run Shell Script".

So far I learned how to make the machine play the sound, but what will be the additional code to make it stop for "n" time and loop?

This is the current Automator workflow:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while :
do
    afplay "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Nada/bell.mp3"
    sleep 60
done
```

If you want to do the same on one line in Terminal:

```
while :; do afplay "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Nada/bell.mp3"; done
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! That works wonderfully.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if this fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi: I'm trying to do something different for the small app I want to make by putting the code in "Terminal" like this: << while : do afplay "Users/user/Library/Application Support/Nada/bell.mp3" sleep 60 done >> (w/o the arrows and all in one line), but it won't work. I wonder why? Is it possible in Terminal? Should I look for another programing language? ____ P.S.: I tried to switch the pic above for privacy reasons but the site won't allow me to post imgs. I'm sorry about that. I posted link to new image though. Thanks.

Comment: @pause-n-loop: Open a new question. Don't post a separate question in a comment.

Comment: but I'll answer your second question, you have to do this:

`while :; do afplay "..."; done`